# What constitutes a proof of congruence in modular arithmetic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> In this problem, don’t use a calculator. The answers can be derived without doing much computation, try to find these simple solutions.
>
> (a) $4 + 5 + 6 ≡ 0 \pmod {5}$

My professor gave me some congruences to prove in my latest discrete HW. They seem pretty easy, but I'm not sure what constitutes a proof. I know that a congruence of numbers $a, b$ and $n$ would have the following characteristics:

1) $a-b$ would be a multiple of $n$

2) $a$ is $b$ more than a multiple of $n$

3) $a / n$ has remainder $b$

...would showing any of these three things to be true (or all three to be true) constitute a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Better: $5\equiv 0\pmod 5$, $6\equiv 1\pmod 5$, and $4\equiv -1\pmod 5$, so $4+5+6\equiv -1+0+1 \equiv 0\pmod 5$.

Comment: This answer is an instance of the general principle that in congruences mod $n$ you rarely have to use large integers because you can reduce mod $n$ _before_ and during any arithmetic. That's why you can do these kinds of problems without a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $4 + 5 + 6 = 15$. Recall the definition of the congruence relation: $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ if and only if $n \big | (a - b)$. So $5 \big | (15 - 0)$, which implies that $4 + 5 + 6 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

All three of those imply $a\equiv b(mod~n)$.

1) $n|(a-b)$

By the definition of modular equivalence, $a\equiv b(mod~n)$

2) $a=kn+b$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Moving the b to the LHS reveals $a-b=kn\Rightarrow n|(a-b)\Rightarrow a\equiv b(mod~n)$

3) "$a/n$ leaves remainder $b$" is the same as "$a=kn+b$ with $0\leq b<n$". This, as in 2), implies $a\equiv b(mod~n)$.

It should be noted that for 3), the converse isn't true, i.e. $a\equiv b(mod~n)$ does NOT imply "$a/n$ leaves remainder $b$". As a counterexample, $5\equiv 3(mod~2)$ but 5 leaves remainder 1, not 3, after division by 2.

Comment: Your number 1 is backwards. It should be $n|(a-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that you can certainly use, as a variation on 1) in your question,

$$a+kn \equiv a \bmod n$$

... effectively, "casting out $n$s", which can be used to good effect in your example question:

\begin{align}
4+5+6 &\equiv 4+6 \bmod 5\\
&\equiv (5-1)+(5+1) \bmod 5\\
&\equiv -1 + 1 \bmod 5  \\
&\equiv 0 \bmod 5\\
\end{align}

or, if using negative numbers in modulus calculations is not yet "approved",

\begin{align}
4+5+6 &\equiv 4+6 \bmod 5\\
&\equiv 4+(5+1) \bmod 5\\
&\equiv 4 + 1 \bmod 5  \\
&\equiv 5 \bmod 5\\
&\equiv 0 \bmod 5\\
\end{align}